# How to tell Traefik 2.1 to use a user-defined wildcard certificate for a router?

Tags: ssl, traefik

I'm trying to get Traefik to use a manually configured wildcard certificate for all routers that have a matching Host rule. I assumed Traefik would try to find a certificate based on the domains used in the Host rule, but it always uses the default generated certificate instead.

traefik.yml

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

log:
  level: DEBUG

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  web-secure:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik/conf
    watch: true
```

dynamic conf:

```
http:
  routers:
    test:
      rule: "Host(`subdomain.wildcard.domain.tld`)"
      entryPoints: ["web"]
      service: service-test
      middlewares: ["https_redirect"]
    test-secure:
      rule: "Host(`subdomain.wildcard.domain.tld`)"
      entryPoints: ["web-secure"]
      service: service-test
      tls: {}

  services:
    service-test:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://helloworld"

  middlewares:
    https_redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true
```

Traefik is running inside a Docker container, based on the log it can see and use the mounted certificate files:

```
time="2020-03-04T10:44:13Z" level=debug msg="No store is defined to add the certificate <...>, it will be added to the default store."
time="2020-03-04T10:44:13Z" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) wildcard.domain.tld,*.wildcard.domain.tld"
time="2020-03-04T10:44:13Z" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
```

However, when doing a curl request, the default certificate is used:

```
curl -k -v --header "Host: subdomain.wildcard.domain.tld" https://192.168.173.143/

* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
*  start date: Mar  4 10:44:13 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar  4 10:44:13 2021 GMT
*  issuer: CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
```

When specifyng the certificate as the default certificate, Traefik does use it, making it more obvious that something is wrong when it tries to match the routers to fitting certificates.

```
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /ssl/wildcard.crt
      keyFile: /ssl/wildcard.key
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: /ssl/wildcard.crt
        keyFile: /ssl/wildcard.key
```

Comment: is the cert a self-signed cert?

Comment: can't believe there is no example for this on official site. Seems very common to me

Comment: Have you tried this answer? `https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268712`