# "No default certificate, generating one" when a default certificate is provided

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, traefik

This probably a newbie question regarding traefik and the SSL configuration.
I'd like to use my own (self-signed, company, ...) certificates with traefik. I tried to follow the documentation, but I keep on getting the following message:

> ... level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"

My `traefik.toml`looks like this:

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

    [entryPoints.web.http]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
            to = "websecure"
            scheme = "https"

    [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[log]
    level = "DEBUG"
[api]
    insecure = true
    dashboard = true
[providers.docker]
    exposedByDefault = false

[[tls]]
  entryPoints = ["websecure"]

[[tls.certificate]]
    certFile = "/certs/cert.crt"
    keyFile = "/certs/cert.key"

[tls.stores]
  [tls.stores.default]
    [tls.stores.default.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/cert/cert.crt"
      keyFile  = "/cert/cert.key"
```

and my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - $PWD/shared/traefik/etc/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - $PWD/shared/traefik/ssl:/certs/

  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.basic-auth-whoami.basicauth.users=***:***"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-whoami.stripprefix.prefixes=/whoami"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=basic-auth-whoami@docker,strip-whoami@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=PathPrefix(`/whoami`) && Host(`<mydomain>`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.whoami-poc-traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.redirs.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true"
```

I am quite sure this is something *trivial* but I can't figure it out (both the toml syntax and traefik concepts being a too much to swallow at once).

Answer (score 12):

I finally found out what was not working by following this [blog](https://containo.us/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/)

I had to:

1. Add file provider for dynamic configuration to my `traefik.toml` file:

   ```
   [providers.file]
   filename = "/tls-certs.toml"
   ```
2. Add a volume mapping to my `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```yaml
   - $PWD/shared/traefik/etc/tls-certs.toml:/tls-certs.toml
   ```
3. Provide a `tls-certs.toml` file:

   ```
   [[tls.certificates]] #first certificate
     certFile = "/certs/cert.crt"
     keyFile = "/certs/cert.key"
   ```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my weekend. file provider was the problem my nomad template was not reloading itself.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I spent several hours trying to find the solution.

Comment: So the solution is to make the wildcard certificate first? What happens when I need Træfik to handle multiple wildcard certificates?