# No default certificate, fallback to the internal generated certificate Traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm suffering to attempt to configure SSL certificates with Traefik reverse proxy.
I am providing a dynamic configuration via a `dynamic-config.yml` and traefik is pretending that no certificates are being found.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://traefik.io/blog/traefik-2-tls-101-23b4fbee81f1/) after finding a person having the [same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256934/no-default-certificate-generating-one-when-a-default-certificate-is-provided), using their solution did not solve the problem.

My docker-compose file is like so,

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    networks:
      - jupyterhub-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./traefik/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml"  # static config
      - "/usr/local/etc/certificates/test.jupyter:/certificates"
      - "./traefik/dynamic-config.yml:/configuration/dynamic-config.yml"
    # configure access to traefik dashboard
    labels: 
      - "traefik.enable=true"


  jupyterhub:
    ...

networks:
  jupyterhub-network:
    name: jupyterhub-network
```

The static `traefik.yml` config file is as follows,

```yaml
log:
  level: DEBUG

api:
  # insecure: true  # since we want a secure api service accessible via https
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  websecure:
    address: ":443" 
  web:
    address: ":80"

providers:
  docker:
    exposedbydefault: false

  file: # specify dynamic config folder
    directory: "/configuration/"
    watch: true
```

`dynamic-conf.yml` is as follows,

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      rule: Host(`mydomain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
      entrypoints:
      - web 
      - websecure
      service: 
      - api@internal
      middlewares: 
      - auth-dashboard   # define a new middleware
      tls: true

  middlewares:
    auth-dashboard:
      basicauth: 
        users: 
        - "admin:$$apr1$$GVsRlau4$$igQmg65r894lgrjOq2/bK." 

tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: "/certificates/fullchain.pem"
      keyFile: "/certificates/privkey.pem"

  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: "/certificates/fullchain.pem"
        keyFile: "/certificates/privkey.pem"
```

Traefik debug logs are the following :

```
level=info msg="Configuration loaded from file: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml"
level=info msg="Traefik version 2.10.4 built on 2023-07-24T16:29:02Z"
level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{\"checkNewVersion\":true},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"web\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":\"10s\"},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":\"3m0s\"}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{},\"http2\":{\"maxConcurrentStreams\":250},\"udp\":{\"timeout\":\"3s\"}},\"websecure\":{\"address\":\":443\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"graceTimeOut\":\"10s\"},\"respondingTimeouts\":{\"idleTimeout\":\"3m0s\"}},\"forwardedHeaders\":{},\"http\":{},\"http2\":{\"maxConcurrentStreams\":250},\"udp\":{\"timeout\":\"3s\"}}},\"providers\":{\"providersThrottleDuration\":\"2s\",\"docker\":{\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":\"15s\"},\"file\":{\"directory\":\"/configuration/\",\"watch\":true}},\"api\":{\"dashboard\":true},\"log\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"common\"}}"
level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/contributing/data-collection/\n"
level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator aggregator.ProviderAggregator"
level=debug msg="Starting TCP Server" entryPointName=web
level=debug msg="Starting TCP Server" entryPointName=websecure
level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider"
level=debug msg="*file.Provider provider configuration: {\"directory\":\"/configuration/\",\"watch\":true}"
level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider"
level=debug msg="*traefik.Provider provider configuration: {}"
level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{\"services\":{\"api\":{},\"dashboard\":{},\"noop\":{}},\"serversTransports\":{\"default\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{},\"tls\":{}}" providerName=internal
level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider"
level=debug msg="*docker.Provider provider configuration: {\"watch\":true,\"endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"defaultRule\":\"Host(`{{ normalize .Name }}`)\",\"swarmModeRefreshSeconds\":\"15s\"}"
level=info msg="Starting provider *acme.ChallengeTLSALPN"
level=debug msg="*acme.ChallengeTLSALPN provider configuration: {}"
level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"dashboard\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"web\",\"websecure\"],\"middlewares\":[\"auth-dashboard\"],\"service\":\"║24║api@internal\",\"rule\":\"Host(`mydomain.com`) \\u0026\\u0026 PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)\",\"tls\":{}}},\"middlewares\":{\"auth-dashboard\":{\"basicAuth\":{\"users\":[\"admin:$$apr1$$GVsRlau4$$igQmg65r894lgrjOq2/bK.\"]}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{},\"tls\":{\"stores\":{\"default\":{}}}}" providerName=file
level=debug msg="Provider connection established with docker 24.0.6 (API 1.43)" providerName=docker
level=debug msg="Configuration received: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"jupyhub\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"websecure\"],\"service\":\"jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala\",\"rule\":\"Host(`mydomain.com`)\"},\"reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala\":{\"service\":\"reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala\",\"rule\":\"Host(`reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala`)\"}},\"services\":{\"jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.19.0.2:8000\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}},\"reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala\":{\"loadBalancer\":{\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http://172.19.0.3:80\"}],\"passHostHeader\":true}}}},\"tcp\":{},\"udp\":{}}" providerName=docker
level=debug msg="No default certificate, fallback to the internal generated certificate" tlsStoreName=default
level=debug msg="No entryPoint defined for this router, using the default one(s) instead: [web websecure]" routerName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala
level=debug msg="No store is defined to add the certificate MIIE9jCCA96gAwIBAgISBMqLmqVsfmd4LpmnS763rvSWMA0GCS, it will be added to the default store."
level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) mydomain.com"
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=websecure routerName=jupyhub@docker serviceName=jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala middlewareName=pipelining
level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" serviceName=jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala entryPointName=websecure routerName=jupyhub@docker
level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.19.0.2:8000" serverName=0 entryPointName=websecure routerName=jupyhub@docker serviceName=jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala
level=debug msg="child http://172.19.0.2:8000 now UP"
level=debug msg="Propagating new UP status"
level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware jupyterhub-jupyhubgrascala" entryPointName=websecure routerName=jupyhub@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure routerName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala@docker serviceName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining
level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" routerName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala@docker serviceName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala entryPointName=websecure
level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://172.19.0.3:80" serverName=0 entryPointName=websecure routerName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala@docker serviceName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala
level=debug msg="child http://172.19.0.3:80 now UP"
level=debug msg="Propagating new UP status"
level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala" routerName=reverse-proxy-jupyhubgrascala@docker middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=websecure
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Recovery entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery
level=error msg="unknown internal service ║24║api@internal" entryPointName=websecure routerName=dashboard@file
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=websecure middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
level=error msg="unknown internal service ║24║api@internal" entryPointName=web routerName=dashboard@file
level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=web middlewareName=traefik-internal-recovery middlewareType=Recovery
level=debug msg="Adding route for mydomain.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=web
level=debug msg="Adding route for mydomain.com with TLS options default" entryPointName=websecure
```

If anybody has an idea, I'm all ears.

Thanks !

The certificate files were issued by my University and I have the following files within my possession :
`cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.jks  fullchain.p12  fullchain.pem  fullchain_java11.jks  log.txt  privkey.pem` 
maybe I'm using the wrong one ? These were generated via let's encrypt.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add more labels to your docker compose, otherwise traefik won't be able to perform service discovery and add the correct configuration for the service. Something along the line:

```
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true" 
    - "traefik.http.routers.jupyterhub.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.http.routers.jupyterhub.tls=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.jupyterhub.rule=Host(`yourhost`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.jupyterhub.service=jupyterhub"
    - "traefik.http.services.jupyterhub.loadbalancer.server.port=YOUR_PORT"
    - "traefik.docker.network=jupyterhub-network"
```